# Compiling a non-standard module into an executable file with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Background: I have had success in the past installing and using Pyinstaller to transform my python projects into one-file executables. I don't think it is an issue with my source code or pyinstaller files.

Problem: I used a free, open-source library/module called easygui imported into my source code to build an application. The application works perfectly run natively or through the Python IDE. I am pretty sure the problem is that Pyinstaller is not finding the EasyGUI module to import (it automatically includes and compiles any libraries you import in the script).

Actions: My python folder is not in the C:\ drive, it is in the E:\ drive. I'm able to access the pyinstaller path in "E:\program files\python" but it is not reading the easygui library, I don't think. I installed pyinstaller and easygui using pip.

Reading a LOT of pyinstaller's documentation i tried to run it to include a paths dir like:

```
    E:\Program Files Hard Disk\Python\Scripts>pyinstaller --paths 
    DIR "E:\Program Files Hard Disk\Python" --onefile "E:\Program Files\Python"
```

It does output the single executable in the build file but does not launch correctly. From what I can see in the console window the brief moment it's up, it looks like an easygui issue. Here is the result of attempting to launch the executable from the command-line:

[image: screenshot]

Here is the compiling in the command window:

[image: screenshot]

Please help

Comment: try running the exe from the command window so you can see the output ... (even after your program exits)

Comment: here is the result of that @JoranBeasley http://i.imgur.com/T0BOTkc.png